# Understanding spring scope in REST application with ldapTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-annotations, spring-bean

I've an application with annotated as RestController autowiring a service implementation.
The service autowires an ldapTemplate scoped as "protoytpe".
As the ldaptemplate is edited for each service method I want to avoid that if the app serves 2 methods at the same time the ldapTemplate messing up with its parameters.

How should I set the scopes? Right now I've the service scoped as default ("singleton") and the ldapTemplate as "prototype".
I'm fine with these settings?

Comment: And creating that every time? How about the performance?

Comment: yes but if I create it as singleton and I've at the same time 2 differents calls how it works?